# Objective-C Encryption libraries on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encryption, aes, 3des

Are there any ready-to-use encryption libraries for the iPhone? 3DES, AES/Rijndael, whatever. I need to encrypt and decrypt strings. My understanding of Objective-C is that you can use C code inside of Objective-C methods/functions/whatever they're called.

Answer (score 4):

iPhone comes out of the box with the CommonCrypto library. It has various support for encryption. See the [Security Coding How-to](http://developer.apple.com/library/#codinghowtos/Security/_index.html) from Apple.

Comment: Yeah, I would go with the Apple-supplied libraries.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011172

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, you can use any C code you want in Objective - C, since it is a proper superset of C.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget you could always use c++ source code in your obj-c project and there are many c++ encryption libraries like : [LibTomCrypt](http://libtomcrypt.com/)

add c++ code to your project and simply call functions;

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.example-code.com/objc/crypt2_3des.asp